# Integrating $\int \frac1{x} dx$ by parts yields $\int\frac1{x}dx=\int\frac1{x}dx-1$. Where's the mistake?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I can't understand where the mistake in the following steps is:

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \int x  \frac{1}{x^2}dx = -\int x (-\frac{1}{x^2})dx = -\int x(\frac{1}{x})'dx = -x\frac{1}{x} + \int \frac{1}{x}dx = -1 + \int \frac{1}{x}dx$$

So: $$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \int \frac{1}{x}dx -1$$

---

Also: Why is it that the integral of this function is $\ln x$? How did people conclude that?

Comment: Arbitrary constant?

Comment: Oh well... silly me.  I should probably only ask the second question.

Comment: Indefinite integrals aren't functions, per se, they're sets of functions that all have the same derivative. The constant is eliminated after differentiation so it doesn't really matter. Regarding how we know that $\int\frac1x\ \mathrm{d}x$ is $\ln x$, that's effectively just the name we give that integral. It's commonly used as a definition of $\ln x$, when you include the limits.

Comment: Many take that as the definition of $\ln x$, i.e. $\ln x = \int _1^x 1/t dt$

Comment: @Antonis: You should ask the second question as a *separate* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int\frac{1}{x}dx$ denotes the set of all antiderivatives of $\frac{1}{x}$. You've shown a function $f$ is such antiderivative iff $f-1$ is too. You need another method to show it's a logarithm. You can note for example that$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x\implies\frac{dx}{dy}=x\implies x\propto\exp y\implies y=\ln x+C.$$(Due to the discontinuity at $x=0$, $C$ in this context is *locally* constant. For example, if $x$ is a real variable, we can choose $y-\ln|x|$ to have a $\operatorname{sign}x$-dependent value that's otherwise constant.)

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to see a method for integrating this. Also in your second step what is the symbol after x, and  in the definite case what is the method?

Comment: @Antonis $u\propto v$ means $u$ is proportional to $v$. (If you want to use this symbol, write `\propto`.) You would compute the definite integral over an interval not containing $0$ using an arbitrary antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for "contradictory looking" result is because you are trying to estimate an indefinite integral. An indefinite integral such as 
$$
\int \frac1x dx
$$
gives a set of answers. So 
$$
\int \frac1x dx = \{f: f(x) = \log x + a \text{ where } a \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
So the equality you got is actually a set equality. That is 
$$
\{f: f(x) = \log x + a \text{ where } a \in \mathbb{R} \} - 1 = \{f: f(x) = \log x + a \text{ where } a \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
and there is nothing wrong mathematically.

Your steps aren't wrong, they just do not account for the set equality that you are showing.

The reason why 
$$
\int \frac1x dx = \log x + a
$$
is mainly due to the definition of exponential function $\exp$ and its relation to the logarithm $\log$.

Comment: Your notation for the set of antiderivatives is slightly incorrect. Due to the discontinuity at $x=0$, there can be *two* independent constants of integration. So the set would actually be $\left\{f: f(x) = \log |x|+\begin{cases}a^+,&x>0\\a^-,&x<0\end{cases},\ \text{where}\ a^+,a^-\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. See [Tom Leinster: Reader Survey: log|x| + C](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/03/reader_survey_logx_c.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the fix.